# jQuery tooltip always on left of page

Tags: jquery, css, tooltip

I have a problem on a page where I am positioning a div absolutely in css and want to trigger a tooltip from that div.

See [Example page showing tooltip effect](http://www.london-electronics.com/1_gantt1_tooltip.php)

The tooltip always opens on the left of the page, well away from the div.

I am at a loss as to how to cure this, any suggestions gratefully received!

Thanks

Graham

Comment: Perhaps you need to review the documentation

Comment: Please post some relevant code here.

Comment: Hi Hashem Qolami, I have posted the page url of a simplified version,  above, with all related code.

Comment: Found the problem! The problem is that the rel="tooltip" is postioned in the containing <td>
Moving it into the <div> corrects the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Number one you have a absolute position on your div that you hover to use the tooltip.  Along with that you have a 16% margin left that offsets the div. This is why your tooltip does not show properly.

Solution 1:

If you remove the position absolute, give your div a fixed width, and if you want the margin spacing you can add the margin spacing at the point.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Cam, many thanks. I need the div to be positioned some distance from the edge, this is an element in a gantt chart. So as you change the window size, the div should appear scaled and offset in pecentage of window width.

Comment: It looks like you saw that you needed to post to the DIV instead of outside the div.